# Astrojs "window is not defined" error, even though i'm using client:only directive

Tags: javascript, client-server, svelte, astrojs

We're trying to use Astro to have a website where each top component can be developed by a different team using whatever framework they want. We start with a very simple example using Svelte as the component framework, with a purely client-side component (notice it calls `window`):

```
// ------index.astro
---
import MyAppTest from '../MyAppTest.svelte'
---
<MyAppTest client:only="svelte"/>

// ------MyAppTest.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  const myhost = window.location.host
  console.log(myhost)
</script>

<div>{myhost}</div>
```

This works perfectly! But if we try to improve the design by moving the function to an outside imported .ts module, it fails:

```
// ------MyAppTest.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import { myhost } from "./myhostlocation"
  console.log(myhost)
</script>

<div>{myhost}</div>

// ------myhostlocation.ts
export const myhost = window.location.host
```

by throwing a "ReferenceError: window is not defined. Browser APIs are not available on the server."

I have already set the `client:only` directive as seen above, and the svelte component works correctly when the `window` call is inside it. **But fails when it is in an imported file. I don't know how to resolve this issue, can anyone help?**

I have already tried setting `client:only="ts"` and `client:only`. It doesn't help. Neither does using .js instead of .ts.

Comment: when exactly do you get that error? when you do `npm run build` for static site generation, or..? seems that the `myhostlocation` module is loaded on the server as well somehow. easy way to fix it would be to make `myHost` a function: `getMyHost = () => window.location.host`

Comment: @mb21 I get it on `npm run dev`, not on `npm run build`. Your solution works, but we wanted astro to use our already-built and tested components. If we're gona have to go re-write each component file to modify each browser API call into a function, we're not going to use astro...

Comment: You must be importing that module somewhere else that's used on the server. Because the code you posted actually works fine by itself: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zxd8nv?file=src%2Fpages%2Findex.astro